# Looping through a variable range

Tags: excel, vba, do-while

I'm quite new to writing Excel VBA scripts, but I am trying to create a script that truncates attendance for an event based on its start and end time. Right now I have a sheet that shows the attendance for an event split among all rooms involved, but the attendance is shown to be for 24 hours of the day. So I am creating a Do While loop that will set attendance to zero for times that are outside of the start and end times, and populate a table with the attendance numbers while within that event time.

The issue is that I am having trouble moving through a range of event times. This is the Table I am trying to populate for reference.

```
Date    Useage  Event Time  Meeting Room 1  Meeting Room 2  Meeting Room 3
01-01-18    3   12:00 AM                                        
01-01-18    3   01:00 AM                                        
01-01-18    3   02:00 AM                                        
01-01-18    3   03:00 AM                                        
01-01-18    3   04:00 AM                                        
01-01-18    3   05:00 AM                                        
01-01-18    3   06:00 AM                                        
01-01-18    3   07:00 AM                                        
01-01-18    3   08:00 AM                                        
01-01-18    3   09:00 AM                                        
01-01-18    3   10:00 AM                                        
01-01-18    3   11:00 AM                                        
01-01-18    3   12:00 PM                                        
01-01-18    3   01:00 PM                                        
01-01-18    3   02:00 PM                                        
01-01-18    3   03:00 PM                                        
01-01-18    3   04:00 PM                                        
01-01-18    3   05:00 PM                                        
01-01-18    3   06:00 PM                                        
01-01-18    3   07:00 PM                                        
01-01-18    3   08:00 PM                                        
01-01-18    3   09:00 PM                                        
01-01-18    3   10:00 PM                                        
01-01-18    3   11:00 PM                                        
01-02-18    3   12:00 AM                                        
01-02-18    3   01:00 AM
```

```
Dim x As Double
Dim y As Double

Dim startTime As Double
Dim eventTime As Range

x = 0
y = 0

startTime = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Attendance").Range("H3")
Set eventTime = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Time Occupancy Analysis").Range("C2")

            Do While (startTime >= eventTime) And y <= 24
                Do While (startTime >= eventTime) And x <= 36
                    eventTime.Offset(0, x + 1) = 0
                    x = x + 1
                    Loop
                x = 0
                Sheets("Time Occupancy Analysis").Range("D2").Offset(y + 1, 0) = 0
                y = y + 1
                eventTime = eventTime + 0.04167 'This is where the problem exists'
                Loop
```

I am hoping for the code to output 0's for attendance until the startTime for the event is equal to the eventTime. When it is run, it changes the eventTime instead of moving through the range of event times (12:00 AM, 1:00 AM, 2:00 AM, etc.)

Comment: `eventTime` being a `Range`, `eventTime = whatever` is implicitly doing `eventTime.Value = whatever`, i.e. "it changes the eventTime" (writes to `C2`). Do you mean to `Set eventTime = eventTime.Offset(1)` or similar?

Comment: Ya I have seen that it is changing the event time in C2. My intent though is for it to read the event time in C2 (12:00 AM), then after populating the associated row with 0's, I want it to move to the next event time (1:00 AM) and populate that row with 0's. And continue this until the Event Time is equal to the Start Time.

Comment: Yes, that's quite literally what `Set eventTime = eventTime.Offset(1)` would do: instead of writing to the `eventTime` range (`C2`), you'd be setting it to the cell underneath it, at each iteration.

Comment: Note that the loop expressions probably need to be adjusted too; I'd think the `Do While {expression}` expression gets re-evaluated every time, so that might be setting you up for an infinite loop (or a rather indirect bail-out when `startTime` is "greater than" what gets evaluated as a `Variant/Empty` at the first empty row). Consider a more straightforward approach instead, like a `For` loop that runs from `2` to the last row in that sheet.

Comment: Wow, that Is an exceptionally easy solution. I just got lost in my own head. Thank you for setting me straight.